# VBA to only run on a certain worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The code below will insert a new row above column 2 whenever the macro is ran. However, if I click a different sheet and run the macro, it inserts a new row in that sheet instead of **Sheet 1** like I had specified. Is there a way to make it so that when I run the macro it will only do those actions on a particular sheet no matter what sheet I am on?

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Put a dot before "Rows"**

Your reference "Rows" is using whatever active Rows (equivalent to ActiveSheet.Rows), but the dot will use the "With" block.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
    .Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```

Without the dot, the With block isn't even considered and the code is equivalent to:

```
 Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

This is also true for the bang operator (!).

Reference:

- [VBA With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266330(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: What a concept. I appreciate it.

Comment: @THATnewbie For additional information, do not forget to visit [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). To know more about coding explicitly in VBA, [this is a good read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).

Comment: @L42 That link is actually not the right one-- it's for Visual Basic .NET

Answer (score 2):

For a single line of code I would not bother with a With statement:

```
Worksheets("Sheet 1").Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 0):

Add '.' in Rows ...

```
With Worksheets("Sheet 1")
     .Rows("2:2").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End With
```